# pass extra variable in an itemRenderer

Tags: variables, actionscript, flex4, itemrenderer

i have a List which uses a an arrayCollection as dataprovider and an itemRenderer to display some things but how can i pass an extra variable to this itemRenderer??
Any help?

for example here:
[adobe flex examples](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/videotraining/exercises/ex4_02.html) 
what if i want to pass an extra variable to declare what is the folder name where the image can be found?

Thanks beforehand!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a ClassFactory:

```
[Bindable]
protected var cf:ClassFactory;//bind your List's itemRenderer property to this

protected function onPreInitialize():void {
   cf = new ClassFactory(YourRenderer);
   //note that {folder='theFolder'} is now {folder:'theFolder'}
   cf.properties = {folder:'theFolder'};//note that your renderer will need to expose a public folder property
}
```

Comment: i did the following as you said:

`[Bindable]protected var cf:ClassFactory;
protected function onPreInitialize():void {
 cf = new ClassFactory(VideoItemRenderer);
 cf.properties = {folder='images'};
 }`
 but it gives me a syntax error and in my VideoItemRenderer i put 
"public var folder:String;" is it ok, and where to i have to call the onPreInitialize() function?

Comment: What is the syntax error? You'll either need to make the folder variable bindable and bind to it or use a getter/setter to do something with the value. In your root mxml tag, set preinitialize="onPreOnitialized".

Comment: expecting colon before assign and expecting identifier before right brace at: cf.properties = {folder='images'};
I also put this<fx:Script>
  <![CDATA[
   [Bindable]public var folder:String;
  ]]>
 </fx:Script>
in my itemrenderer and did the preinitialize at the component that calls the itemrenderer are these ok?

Comment: i do the following:
   `[Bindable]protected var cf:ClassFactory;
   protected function onPreInitialize():void {
    cf = new ClassFactory(VideoItemRenderer);
    cf.properties = {folder : 'images'};
   }` 
in my component and i component and this `<fx:Script>
  <![CDATA[
   import mx.controls.Alert;
   [Bindable]public var folder:String;
   
   public function onCreation():void
   {
    Alert.show(folder);
   }
  ]]>
 </fx:Script>` in my itemRenderer bt the folder variable seems to have no value at the Alert...any idea?

Comment: In addition i have this in my itemRenderer to show the image:
`<s:Image left="0" right="0" top="44" bottom="0" scaleMode="stretch" smooth="false"
      source="{folder}/{data.thumb}"/>`